# SQL Join - May need Nested SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join, nested

Hi I am trying to do a SQL join but am having some trouble.

Here is my dataset.  I want to find all creditcards that used an employee discount then use this list to do an inner join to df1.

DF1

```
   Date          creditcard_number    transaction_number   store
   2017-11-01    1234567891234567     1                    1
   2017-01-01    1234567891234568     2                    1
   2017-11-01    1234567891234567     3                    1
   2017-01-01    1234567891234568     4                    1
```

DF2

```
   Date              transaction_number   store  emp_disc
   2017-11-01        1                    1      103431
```

Goal - df (noticed it is filtered for only cards that had an emp_disc to it)

```
   Date          creditcard_number    transaction_number   store   emp_disc
   2017-11-01    1234567891234567     1                    1       103431
   2017-11-01    1234567891234567     3                    1       103431
```

Comment: What is the JOIN you've attempted so far?

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Comment: See [MySQL joins made easy tutorials](http://googleweblight.com/i?u=http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/&hl=en-CM&tg=230&tk=16291714873090022363), you should be able to do this after reading this tutorial.

Comment: @Strawberry is right -- *always* include your broken code, and use it to make your question much more specific. This isn't a traditional "help" site but rather a question and answer site where the goal is to create questions and answers that help future visitors, not just you the asker. It is standard on this site for folks to try to coerce you to improve your question, and you should take this in stride.

Comment: @aidenrosenblatt Questions that follow the pattern -- I am trying to do this and here is my code that doesn't work.. please help me fix this, always get better response on SO.

Answer (score 0):

**In MySQL**
Try:

```
SELECT A.*, B.transaction_number, B.store, B.emp_disc
FROM DF1 A INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM DF2 WHERE emp_disc IS NOT NULL) B
ON A.`DATE`=B.`DATE`;
```

See mysqltutorial.org for insights.

Comment: I don't see how this could add the col for emp_disc.  my way has been creating two separate dataframes then joining them together but it isn't very efficient in this manner.

Comment: Provide the information about the employee discount in your question then. I don't know where you are coming up with `emp_disc`!

Comment: goal-df has emp_disc it is given from df2

Comment: Provide a sample data in your question. I am not in your head to know what you want! Your question is not complete.

Comment: df1 and df2 are sample.  goal - df is what i want to achieve

Comment: I just updated my answer. I am sorry I didn't notice your data sample was complete because I am browsing from my phone. No horizontal scrollbar is displayed to indicate more info.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right, I think the following query will serve your needs:

```
SELECT DF1.*, DF2.emp_disc 
FROM DF1 
JOIN DF2 ON DF2.transaction_number = DF1.transaction_number 
        AND DF2.store = DF1.store
WHERE DF2.emp_disc IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: sorak, i don't think this will work.  I am trying to use df1 and df2 to make goal df.

Comment: The result set is what you ask for as "DF" ... that label does not need to exist anywhere in the query, unless you are asking for the creation of a new table (which I do not believe is the case)

Comment: What you posted above seems to indicate that your desired output is the entire record from DF1 and just the related emp_disc value from DF2, correct? That is what this query should provide for you.

Comment: i am looking for the 1st the 3rd transaction from df1, based on the criteria that creditcard1234567891234567 appeared in df2.  i also want the emp_disc associated with 1234567891234567  to appear in the final output

Comment: DF2 does not contain any creditcard_number information

Comment: df2 has the transaction number though

Comment: Yes, but you have the emp_disc value displayed associated with a different transaction number. There are two different transactions for that credicard_number value from DF1

Comment: i don't know how to solve this in sql which is why i am asking for help. I know how to solve it is you create two separate tables then join.  I was thinking a nested function could eliminate the need to create two tables

Comment: These are two different sets of data, so they need to be in two tables. You relate the data in two tables by JOINing on foreign keys, common values that unite the tables. transaction_id values should be unique, so you don't need to duplicate the store information in df2, which appears to be a table holding the items related to a purchase.